# How to see all tcp ports listened on locally

Tags: networking, tcp, netstat

I have a WSL2 instance with Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed microk8s and enabled the local registry. The local Registry in microk8s listens on node port 32000. I can access this registry in WSL on both localhost and WSL instance IP. But if I run netstat -an there is none listening on port 32000. I tried a tip to list iptables rules, but nothing mentioning port 32000.
I can start `netcat -l -s <wsl ip> -p 32000` just as none is using it. If I then `curl -v <wsl ip>:32000` I get a response from microk8s registry, not netcat. If I now run netstat, it lists netcat listening on port 32000.

How is this possible? How can curl connect to this port no one is listening on (according to netstat)? How can I open this port for listening using netcat while registry obviously is already listening on it?

Comment: Try again, but use `iptables-save -c`.

Comment: Where are you running netstat? WSL runs in a virtual machine, netstat shows what listens locally not in all local VM's - from your workstation's perspective, the VMs are like external computers on the network.

Comment: Consider revising the title of your question. It appears to be asking for a simple linux command but is actually asking multiple detailed questions about why something is happening in a virtualized network environment.